# Unable to Install MemSQL 6.8.5 on Ubuntu, Nodes Already Exist Yet Unable to Remove

Tags: nodes, singlestore

I've had a series of unsuccessful attempts at installing MemSQL 6.8.5 on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS machine. The bottomline is I'm unable to fully install this software since MemSQL claims I already have nodes installed preventing an install. When I attempt to view the MemSQL nodes I have installed, MemSQL returns 'no nodes found.'

Would anyone happen to have an idea how to resolve this issue?

## Example:

**prompt#: memsql-deploy cluster-in-a-box --license [license]**

*The target user user on host 127.0.0.1 does not have the privileges to perform this action.

Please enter your password to proceed with sudo.  (For details, see https://docs.memsql.com/toolbox-redir/sudo-prompt).
sudo password for user@127.0.0.1: 
memsql-deploy will perform the following actions:
  · Install memsql-server 6.8.5 locally
  · Deploy a master aggregator on port 3306
  · Deploy a leaf node on port 3307*

Would you like to continue? [y/N]: y
✓ Downloaded memsql-server 6.8.5
Installing MemSQL locally...
✓ MemSQL 6.8.5 already installed
Starting rollback
✓ Installed MemSQL 6.8.5
✓ Rollback succeeded
MemSQL nodes already exist on this host. To view them, run 'memsql-admin list-nodes'. To remove them, run 'memsql-admin stop-node --all' then 'memsql-admin delete-node --all'

**prompt#: memsql-admin list-nodes'**

*No nodes found*

Comment: FYI the author also created a thread at https://www.memsql.com/forum/t/unable-to-install-memsql-6-8-5-on-ubuntu-nodes-already-exist-yet-unable-to-remove/1078 where this is being answered

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that MemSQL isn't deployed by checking the default install path?

```
ls /var/lib/memsql*
```

If you see something like:

`memsql/master-XXXX-xxxxxxx/` then delete that directory and try to perform the deployment again.

Comment: Hey, that directory does NOT exist. However, I realized MemSQL has their own community forum (after creating this thread), so I'll move the discussion over there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Apparently I had mysqld also using port 3306.

Consider this resolved.